# In SAS I need counter variable when the group of rows changes

Tags: sas, unique, counter, group

I want to create ID in SAS every time the basket value changes.

[image]

I tried hash and first. with count+1 but all of them shows group A as one ID.

Comment: Welcome :-) Show us your data in the form of a data step and the code you have already tried. Nevermind that it did not work for you.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the new number when you get to the next LOAN number?

Answer (score 1):

Use BY group processing.  Since your BASKET values appear to be grouped but not actually sorted use the NOTSORTED keyword.  A SUM statement is a simple way to create a new variable whose value is retained.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by loan basket NOTSORTED ;
  id + first.basket ;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry Tom, this does not work

Answer (score 0):

I worked with some data I made up myself:

```
data HAVE;
    do Loan_no = 123 to 234 by 7;
        do Basket = "A", "B", "C", "D";
            do none = "there", "we", "go";
                do sense = 1 to 2;
                    output;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

As variables are by default re-initialized for each observation, you need to `retain` your counter and initialise it to zero .
To detect the beginning of a group, with `first.Basket`, you need to process the data `by Load_no Basket`, but not require the dataset to be sorted alphabetically.

Then the solution is

```
data WANT;
    set have;
    retain id 0; 
    by Loan_no Basket notsorted;
    if first.Basket then id = id + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Had a look om my smartphone, because on PC the picture is blocked. Now I understand and will correct it.